# Adding a non-SQL where clause to LINQ-2-SQL

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a Linq-2-SQL that updates the `IEnumerable<Locum> LeftOverLocums` before the inner `foreach` loop. I need to add one more boolean clause to the `Where` portion but it has nothing to do with SQL DB. In fact, its a utility function. Please see the two function below. First one is the main function and the second is the one I need to embed in the `Where` portion.

```
    private void PreferenceFindJobs(ref JobCustomList jobList) {
        List<KeyValuePair<long, DateTime>> AlreadyPrefferedLocums = new List<KeyValuePair<long, DateTime>>();

        List<long> LocumsFilteringIDs = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => Convert.ToInt64(col.Id)).ToList();

        IEnumerable<Locum> LeftOverLocums = null;

        foreach (JobCustom oneJob in jobList) {

            LeftOverLocums = from locums in DbContext.Locums
                                             join availabilities in DbContext.Availabilities on new {
                                                 OID = locums.OID
                                             } equals new {
                                                 OID = availabilities.LocumID
                                             }
                                             where
                                               LocumsFilteringIDs.Contains(locums.OID) &&
                                               locums.IsActive == true &&
                                               locums.IsLocumsExciteBan == false &&
                                               locums.IsGPHCBan == false &&
                                               locums.IsRPSGBBan == false &&
                                               locums.IsAdminMarkedComplete == true &&
                                               availabilities.AvailabilityStatusID == 1 &&
                                               availabilities.AvailableDate == oneJob.JobDate
                                             select locums;

            foreach (Locum oneLocum in LeftOverLocums) {
                    //This Locum can do this job

                    //Now check if he/she has been just alloted
                    if (AlreadyPrefferedLocums.Any(check => check.Key == oneLocum.OID && check.Value == oneJob.JobDate) == false) {
                        //No? Cool!
                        oneJob.LocumID = oneLocum.OID;
                        oneJob.LocumName = oneLocum.FirstName + " " + oneLocum.LastName;

                        //Add to the list to prevent double allocation
                        AlreadyPrefferedLocums.Add(new KeyValuePair<long, DateTime>(oneJob.LocumID, oneJob.JobDate));

                    } else {
                        continue;

                    }

            }

        }
    }

    public enum LocumType {
        Pharmacist = 1,
        Dispenser = 2,
        AccreditedCheckingTechnician = 3
    }

    public static Boolean IsJobTypeOK(Enumerations.LocumType _Job, Enumerations.LocumType _Locum) {
        bool ProcessResult;

        switch (_Job) {
            case  Enumerations.LocumType.Pharmacist:
            ProcessResult = _Locum == Enumerations.LocumType.Pharmacist;
            break;

            case Enumerations.LocumType.Dispenser:
            ProcessResult = _Locum == Enumerations.LocumType.Dispenser;
            break;

            case Enumerations.LocumType.AccreditedCheckingTechnician:
            ProcessResult = _Locum == Enumerations.LocumType.AccreditedCheckingTechnician || _Locum == Enumerations.LocumType.Dispenser;
            break;

            default:
            ProcessResult = false;
            break;
        }

        return ProcessResult;
    }
```

This is my desired `Where` clause:

```
where
    IsJobTypeOK(oneJob.JobTypeID, locums.LocumTypeID) &&
    LocumsFilteringIDs.Contains(locums.OID) &&
    locums.IsActive == true &&
    locums.IsLocumsExciteBan == false &&
    locums.IsGPHCBan == false &&
    locums.IsRPSGBBan == false &&
    locums.IsAdminMarkedComplete == true &&
    availabilities.AvailabilityStatusID == 1 &&
    availabilities.AvailableDate == oneJob.JobDate
```

Comment: I don't see what the issue is here? You can call utility methods in a where clause. Maybe update the question with what error you are getting or something?

Comment: It was my understanding that the Where clause in a LINQ2SQL requires SQL server related queries only.

Comment: Hassan, you are right, LINQ 2 SQL is not available to execute your function. because the query would have to be executed in SQL Server. SQL server doesn't have access to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use the method "IsJobTypeOK" at all.

```
where
(
  (oneJob.JobTypeID == Enumerations.LocumType.AccreditedCheckingTechnician && 
     locums.LocumTypeID == Enumerations.LocumType.Dispenser) || 
  oneJob.JobTypeID == locums.LocumTypeID
) &&
LocumsFilteringIDs.Contains(locums.OID) &&
locums.IsActive == true &&
locums.IsLocumsExciteBan == false &&
locums.IsGPHCBan == false &&
locums.IsRPSGBBan == false &&
locums.IsAdminMarkedComplete == true &&
availabilities.AvailabilityStatusID == 1 &&
availabilities.AvailableDate == oneJob.JobDate
```

Comment: If you look at the `IsJobTypeOK()` method, you'll see it not a simple 'locums.LocumTypeID == oneJob.JobTypeID'

Comment: If you take a look again to your method IsJobTypeOK() the only way you return true is when JobType is the same as you locum.LocumTypeID, unless the JobTypeID is a different enumeration, But you are using exactly the same type for both arguments.

Comment: Please see the last `Case` statement

Comment: ok, I see, then you can do
`where ((oneJob.JobTypeID == AccreditedCheckingTechnician && locums.LocumTypeID == Dispenser) || oneJob.JobTypeID == locums.LocumTypeID) && ...`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to filter the results after you call them from the database.

```
//Get you LeftOverLocums like you are now
//then
LeftOverLocums = LeftOverLocums
                 .Where(l => l.IsJobTypeOK(oneJob.JobTypeID, l.LocumTypeID))
```

Doesn't require anything extra on the database

Comment: It may require pulling unnecessary records from the database in order to run this function in the processing machine. If the SQL Server can process the whole query pass it to SQL. It depends on how many records you are processing.